# Collaborative Paint App

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am in the early stages of learning nodejs client/server programming, for my first application I just want to make a simple collaborative drawing app like paint. So far I have this code and the only thing that seems to work is that my click properly calls in my console.log but no rectangle draws at the click location. Any help? I am pretty new to this.

```js
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
 
 SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
 
 var self = {
  x:0,
  y:0,
  cx:0,
  cy:0,
 }
 
 socket.on('mousePos', function(data){
  self.x = data.x;
  self.y = data.y;
  //console.log('x:' + self.x + ' y:' + self.y);
 });
 
 socket.on('mouseClick', function(data){
  self.cx = data.x;
  self.cy = data.y;
  console.log('x:' + self.cx + ' y:' + self.cy);
 });
 
 socket.emit('paint', {x:self.cx, y:self.cy}); 
 
 /*for (var i in SOCKET_LIST){
  var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
  socket.emit('paint', {x:self.cx, y:self.cy}); 
 }*/
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

<div id="gameCanvasDiv">
 <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</div>
 
<script>
 var socket = io();
 
 var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
 
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
 
 setInterval(function(){
  
  
    },40);
 
 document.onmousedown = function(event){
  
  socket.emit('mouseClick', {x:event.clientX, y:event.clientY});
 
 }
 
 document.onmouseup = function(event){
  
  socket.on('paint', function(data){
   ctx.fillRect(data.x,data.y,10,10);
  });
  
 }
 
 document.onmousemove = function(event){
        socket.emit('mousePos', {x:event.clientX, y:event.clientY});
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onmouseup = function(event){
    socket.on('paint', function(data){
        ctx.fillRect(data.x,data.y,10,10);
    });
}
```

Here you only subscribing to event. So you saying - "When mouse up, please, add one more handler for paint event" (so this code will be executed multiple times). So where paint event generated? Who send it? You send it only once, when connection established. So what you have to do, is to:

1. Mode paint event listener on frontend to outside of event listener.
2. Remove emit('paint') from onConnection event.
3. Add onMouseUp event listener to nodejs.
4. Then send this event to nodejs from onMouseUp event on client side.
5. Then update coordinates in node and generate paint event.
6. On frontend listen for paint event and draw image.